# Difference in usage between "сюда", "здесь", and "тут"

Tags: словоупотребление, значения

> Поэтому я приехала **сюда**.
>
> {X}: Поэтому я приехала **тут**.
>
> {X}: Поэтому я приехала **здесь**.

I wonder why you can only use the adverb "сюда" in this instance, although all three seem to share the locative meaning "here".

Another example where this time around "здесь" seems to fit:

> Как же **здесь** красиво!
>
> {X}: Как же **тут** красиво!
>
> {X}: Как же **сюда** красиво!

Comment: "Азохен вей, товарищи бояре! Я князя Шуйского не вижу среди тут."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because **сюда** means `to here` just like **туда** means `to there` which are in use with verbs of movement and direction.

**Здесь/тут** mean simply `here` and are adverbs of place and not of direction.

Consider English archaic **hither/thither**.

Comment: Hi. How does "вот" in the sense of "here" compare with "здесь/тут"? Woman: "What are you doing here?" Man: "Ничего. Сижу **вот**, жду её."

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens hi, in this sentence ***вот*** means ***well*** - ***Well, nothing, just sitting waiting for her***, ***вот*** here can't really be replaced with тут/здесь, the latter would impart the phrase a grumpy tenor, plus one can say ***вот сижу здесь/тут*** (which sounds just slightly grumpy), in English ***here*** (omitted in my translation) feels like necessary as without it the phrase is somewhat dry, but in my view it's not an equivalent of ***вот*** in this particular case

Answer (score 1):

Здесь (formal ), тут (colloquial ), opposite там are synonyms and show place. There's one more colloquial form туточки.

Сюда -opposite туда shows destination or direction, when you move.

Answer (score -2):

I think тут is more exact than здесь. I saw an old Russian documentary about the creation of the CIS. One old guy was talking about where they signed that document to create the CIS and he used тут as he indicated the lines where people signed the document. He pointed downward too. Здесь is a more general "here".

Comment: one can easily can use "подпишите здесь"  and "подпишите [вот] тут [вот]" interchangeably